# Laravel PHPUnit Test Run Produces Exception The default factory can not be set after the scheduler has been created

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

When I run my laravel tests indivudually with the filter option the tests pass, but when you run all tests without the filter option, It returns an exception

```
Exception: The default factory can not be set after the scheduler has been created
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure that my test database was being migrated and seeds working by adding an artisan call to my setup method in the TestCase class.

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    Artisan::call("migrate", ['--env' => "testing"]);
    Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => SomeTableSeeder::class]);
}
```